# Convert Unix Timestamp to Datetime in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, m

Good morning Stack Overflow,

I have a question, I do have a list of Timestamp, I believe there are Unix Time Stamp, I'd like to convert to datetime on PBI, but I'm getting an error, using the following formula :' #datetime(1957,1,1,0,0,0) + #duration(0,0,0,[Timestamp]) ' , Timestamp is the column that I'd like to convert.

Below a sample list of the data :

[image]

Is there a way to fix this issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're close but you need to remember that Unix timestamps are recorded in milliseconds since 1970, not seconds since 1957. Try this instead

```
#datetime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0) + #duration(0, 0, 0, [Timestamp]/1000)
```

Make sure the column is a `datetime` data type.